# Android - Fill Path with color partially

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I am trying to draw a heart shaped Canvas using Path in Android. The code is as follows :

```
 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        // Fill the canvas with background color
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
       // paint.setShader(null);

        // Defining of  the heart path starts
        path.moveTo(left + WIDTH / 2, top + HEIGHT / 4); // Starting point
        // Create a cubic Bezier cubic left path
        path.cubicTo(left+WIDTH/5,top,
                left+WIDTH/4,top+4*HEIGHT/5,
                left+WIDTH/2, top+HEIGHT);
        // This is right Bezier cubic path
        path.cubicTo(left + 3 * WIDTH / 4, top + 4 * HEIGHT / 5,
                left + 4 * WIDTH / 5, top,
                left + WIDTH / 2, top + HEIGHT / 4);

         paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, canvas.getHeight()/4, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()/4, new int[]{Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN}, new float[]{0, 0.6f, 1}, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        heart_outline_paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.heart_outline_color)); // Change the boundary color
        heart_outline_paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        heart_outline_paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawPath(path, heart_outline_paint);



    }
```

I am able to draw heart without any issue and I am able to fill color inside the heart using the `Fill` option in Paint. But I should be able to fill the heart dynamically according to some data and it cannot be filled fully all the time. What I have achieved so far is as follows :

[image: Heart Shape with Filled Color]

I have made an extensive search and came across a lot of things similar to this. Some of which includes :

1. [Android fill in part of a path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488151/android-fill-in-part-of-a-path)
2. [filling a circle gradually from bottom to top android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858531/filling-a-circle-gradually-from-bottom-to-top-android/24866667?noredirect=1#comment38644747_24866667)

I also came across the concept of converting the canvas to bitmap and filling color inside the bitmap using [Flood Fill Algorithm](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364413/Queue-Linear-Flood-Fill-A-Fast-Flood-Fill-Algorith) which lets users to fill colors inside the bitmap. However, I do not want the bitmap to fill the color while touching inside the heart but to fill while a button click action.

I thought that [filling a circle gradually from bottom to top android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858531/filling-a-circle-gradually-from-bottom-to-top-android/24866667?noredirect=1#comment38644747_24866667)
would give help me but it makes use of a circle and I am not well-versed in Canvas which makes me very weak in adapting the circle code to such a shape.

If anybody has some ideas or any insights on how to achieve this, it will be really helpful. Cheers. Thanks in advance.

**P.S :** I also tried some tricks using `setShader` in Paint but nothing would give me what I want.

**EDIT :**

I just stumbled upon a idea of drawing a rectangle over the heart with another color same as the background of the canvas so that it will look like its half filled !! I am still working on the idea and not sure how accurate this is gonna be for me. If someone has a better idea, you're most welcome.

[image]

Comment: `"But I should be able to fill the heart dynamically according to some data and it cannot be filled fully all the time."` which means in practice ?

Comment: Like the heart has to be filled 10% or 20% depending upon the points acquired by the user.

Comment: I used what you mentioned of drawing a rectangle over the heart fill, but behind the heart border. Worked great for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `clipPath` function available in Canvas to achieve what I needed. I draw the heart by above method and draw a rectangle over it, and I use the `clipPath`function to clip out the region that is outside the heart.

```
     public static double filled_amount = .90;
     path.moveTo(left_x_moveto, left_y_moveto);
     path.cubicTo(left_x1, left_y1, left_x2, left_y2, left_x3, left_y3);
     path.cubicTo(right_x2, right_y2, right_x1, right_y1, left_x_moveto, left_y_moveto);
     path.close();
     Rect rect = new Rect((int)(canvas.getWidth()*.10),(int)(canvas.getHeight()*filled_amount),(int) canvas.getWidth(), (int) canvas.getHeight());
        canvas.clipPath(path); 
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, rect_paint);
        heart_outline_paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.heart_outline_color)); // Change the boundary color
        heart_outline_paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
        heart_outline_paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawPath(path, heart_outline_paint);
```

This will give me the desired result of filling the heart dynamically. Changing the value of `filled_amount` dynamically and calling `invalidate()` will make it look like the heart is being filled dynamically.

@Henry's answer might be a better one but this did the trick for me and I dont look deeply in to the edges so a bit of zig-zags here and there is all right.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Bitmap Masking` to get a partially filled Heart. What you ideally do here is use one bitmap to mask the other.

In your case you could have a filled rectangle in the canvas and you have then have the `heart` shape in a new bitmap to act as the mask. You could then dynamically change the filling of the heart by changing the height of the background rectangle.

Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33483600/4747587. This contains the implementation of **partially filling a Star**. The idea is the same.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I had achieved by using Path in Canvas and the clipPath function.

Comment: Yes. But the `clipPath` does not support anti-aliasing. Based on different shape, you might start to see zig-zag edges. If you are not into too much details, and if the shape is a suitable one, then `clipPath` would work fine.

Comment: I am not much into details so clipPath works perfectly for me, thanks for your valuable suggestion though.